# Add new issue status to existing Redmine Projects

Tags: issue-tracking, redmine

I'm running Redmine 1.1.2.stable and I've just added a couple of new issue statuses to the standard enumeration in the admin interface.

The problem is that these don't appear in my existing projects, though if I rename an existing status entry (i.e. I change "Feedback" to "Feedback Given") then this will be updated throughout all projects. If I add a new status, it will not be shown.

These new status entries don't even appear on a new project.

I haven't taken a look at the MySQL database yet, and wanted to know if there was a simple application setting that I'd overlooked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add them to the workflow of the projects trackers.
Look under /workflows/edit. Don't forget to uncheck "Only display statuses that are used by this tracker". Common mistake...